# Extract date from given string in r

Tags: r, date-formatting

```
string<-c("Posted 69 months ago (7/4/2011)")
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(string, "(.*)", simplify = TRUE)
```

I apply above function but nothing  happens.

In this I want to extract only date part i.e `7/4/2011`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first one shows how to fix the code in the question to give the desired answer. The next 2 solutions are the same except they use different regular expressions.  The fourth solution shows how to do it with `gsub`. The fifth breaks the `gsub` into two `sub` calls and the sixth uses `read.table`.

**1) Escape parens** The problem is that ( and ) have special meaning in regular expressions so you must escape them if you want to match them literally.  By using `"[(]"` as we do below (or writing them as `"\\("` ) they are matched literally.  The inner parentheses define the capture group as we don't want that group to include the literal parentheses themselves:

```
strapplyc(string, "[(](.*)[)]", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "7/4/2011"
```

**2) Match content** Another way to do it is to match the data itself rather than the surrounding parentheses.  Here `"\\d+"` matches one or more digits:

```
strapplyc(string, "\\d+/\\d+/\\d+", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "7/4/2011"
```

You could specify the number of digits if you want to be even more specific but it seems unnecessary here if the data looks similar to that in the question.

**3) Match 8 or more digits and slashes** Given that there are no other sequences of 8 or more characters consisting only of slashes and digits in the rest of the string we could just pick out that:

```
strapplyc(string, "[0-9/]{8,}", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "7/4/2011"
```

**4) Remove text before and after** Another way of doing it is to remove everything up to the ( and after the ) like this:

```
gsub(".*[(]|[)].*", "", string)
## [1] "7/4/2011"
```

**5) sub** This is the same as (4) except it breaks the `gsub` into two `sub` invocations, one removing everything up to ( and the other removing ) onwards.  The regular expressions are therefore slightly simpler.

```
sub(".*\\(", "", sub("\\).*", "", string))
```

**6) read.table**  This solution uses no regular expressions at all.  It defines `sep` and `comment.char` in `read.table` so that the second column of the result of `read.table` is the required date or dates.

```
read.table(text = string, sep = "(", comment.char = ")", as.is = TRUE)$V2
## [1] "7/4/2011"
```

**7) trimws** This trims everything on either end to the ( or ) and then trims the ( and ).

```
string |>
  trimws(whitespace = "[^()]") |>
  trimws(whitespace = "[()]")
## [1] "7/4/2011"
```

**Note:** Note that you don't need the `c` in defining `string`

```
string <- c("Posted 69 months ago (7/4/2011)")
string2 <- "Posted 69 months ago (7/4/2011)"
identical(string, string2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: superb variety of options, thank you for the thorough answer

Answer (score 6):

We can do this with `gsub` by matching one or more characters that are not a `(` (`[^(]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string or `|` the `)` at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with `""`

```
gsub("[^[^(]+\\(|\\)$", "", string)
#[1] "7/4/2011"
```

Or using capture groups

```
sub("^[^(]+\\(([^)]+).*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "7/4/2011"
```

---

Or with `str_extract`, we match one or more characters that are not a `)` (`[^)]+`) that follows the `(` (`(?<=[(])`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "(?<=[(])[^)]+")
#[1] "7/4/2011"
```