# issue extracting date part from various formats in an unstructured text

Tags: r, regex, datetime, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract only date part from a bunch of unstructured text.

Issue is, the date could be in any of the following formats:

- Jan. 16  or Jan 16 2017 (for January 16th, 2017)
- Januray 2, 2017
- 02/01/2017 (dd/mm/yyyy)
- 01/02/2017 (mm/dd/yyyy)
- 01-02-17 (mm-dd-yy)

Sample Text:

```
x <- "There is a date which is Jan 2, 2017. Here is another date example 02/01/2017. This is third example date type [01/02/17]. This is fourth example date Jan. 16 and finally one more example is 01-02-2017"
```

What I was trying is one of the other options (from the examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405615/extract-date-from-given-string-in-r) answer):

```
gsub(".*[(]|[)].*", "", string)
```

Any other generalized possibility?

Comment: Is 'Januray' a typo or is it actually a scenario you need to account for?

Comment: May be [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/zYZAYI/1) can be a start.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to match parentheses when your sample text doesn't contain any. Secondly, escaping special characters with square brackets is generally bad practice because that's also how you create character sets, and some special characters don't get escaped that way or take on different meanings (`^` for example). Just use `\\`.

Comment: @KenS. Thanks for pointing out. yes it is a Typro.

Comment: @CAustin - actually this is just a SAMPLE TEXT from a large document which has parenthesis also.

Comment: I understand that, but your sample text has nothing to do with the regex pattern you posted. What's the point of a sample that provides no relevant information?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Without knowing the date format, for this instance 02/03/2002  you can not tell whether a day is a day and a month is a month.... and in case year can be 2 digit too... eg dd/mm/yy or yy/mm/dd or mm/yy/dd ... you can not say which one is day, which one is month and which one is year...

Taking all these things into account... there could be strings that may come from third party on which you may not have any way to determine the format ... thus no solution can guarantee to define day or month or year for you.

But it is possible to identify all the digit patterns that you have mentioned. The following solution will give you **three group**. You will get the three part of your date for all the formats that you have mentioned in **group 1,2 and 3**. You will have to analyze / guess a way to figure which one is day, which one is month, and which one is year. That can't be covered by regex.

Taking all these facts into account, you may try the following regex:

```
((?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z ]*\.?)|(?:\d{1,2}))[\/ ,-](\d{1,2})(?:[\/ ,-]\s*(\d{4}|\d{2}))?
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5XqDLE/1)

Sample Source ( [run here](http://rextester.com/SPZM76222) ):

```
library(stringr)
str<-"Jan. 16  bla bla bla Jan 16 2017 bla bla bla January 2, 2017 bla bla bla 02/01/2017 bla bla bla 01/02/2017 bla bla bla 01-02-17 bla bla bla jan. 16 There is a date which is Jan 2, 2017. Here is another date example 02/01/2017. This is third example date type [01/02/17]. This is fourth example date Jan. 16 and finally one more example is 01-02-2017"
patt <- "(?i)((?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z ]*\\.?)|(?:\\d{1,2}))[\\/ ,-](\\d{1,2})(?:[\\/ ,-]\\s*(\\d{4}|\\d{2}))?"
result<-str_match_all(str,patt)
result
```

Sample Output:

```
      [,1]              [,2]      [,3] [,4]  
 [1,] "Jan. 16"         "Jan."    "16" ""    
 [2,] "Jan 16 2017"     "Jan"     "16" "2017"
 [3,] "January 2, 2017" "January" "2"  "2017"
 [4,] "02/01/2017"      "02"      "01" "2017"
 [5,] "01/02/2017"      "01"      "02" "2017"
 [6,] "01-02-17"        "01"      "02" "17"  
 [7,] "jan. 16"         "jan."    "16" ""    
 [8,] "Jan 2, 2017"     "Jan"     "2"  "2017"
 [9,] "02/01/2017"      "02"      "01" "2017"
[10,] "01/02/17"        "01"      "02" "17"  
[11,] "Jan. 16"         "Jan."    "16" ""    
[12,] "01-02-2017"      "01"      "02" "2017"
```

Comment: Rizwan, thanks. but how will it matter? for example 2nd feb 2002 can be written either ways 02/02/2002 (dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy)  or 02/02/02 (dd/mm/yy or yy/dd/mm or mm/yy/dd) it all the same, right? and a logic should be able to match it and bring into approprite common final format. right?

Comment: What about 02/03/2002 then is it 2nd of March or 3rd of February ?

Comment: The point is .... by the above regex you will get 3 parts for sure... it is definitely going to be upto you ... to decide what logic you want to put over it to determine day, month or year

Comment: i agree. but there should be some way out? :-(

Comment: let's forget all regex or everything .. just think simple i tell you 02/03/01 but dont tell you date format.... what do you get from it ? There is a way out, the party who is sending you the data **may** know the format... they have got to share it ...