# R substring - extracting date from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a character variable that lists values as so:

```
76GA14, Week 1, 05/13/2014, ABC
76GA14, Week 4, 02/08/2016, ABC
76GA15, Week 3, 09/02/2016, ABC
76GA15, Week 8, 01/19/2015, ABC
76GA16, Week 1, 11/28/2018, ABC
76GA18, Day 0, 12/07/2015, ABC
76GA18, Day 2 End, 11/22/2016, ABC
76GA17, W4 end 6DNV118, 07/06/2016, ABC
...
```

I want to extract only the date (`dd/mm/yyyy`) and set create a new variable column with those values.

Comment: strapplyc(string, "\\d+/\\d+/\\d+", simplify = TRUE)  might work for you. 
here is the link you can follow it has more details. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405615/extract-date-from-given-string-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this.

Here is my suggestion:

```
charVector <- c("76GA14, Week 1, 05/13/2014, ABC",
                "76GA14, Week 4, 02/08/2016, ABC",
                "76GA15, Week 3, 09/02/2016, ABC",
                "76GA15, Week 8, 01/19/2015, ABC",
                "76GA16, Week 1, 11/28/2018, ABC")

newVariable <- sapply(strsplit(charVector, ", "), "[", 3)
```