# How to extract date from a multiline string or File in R

Tags: r

Suppose there is a file with a multi-line string like:

/*Analysis made on 28 september 2011
people who exercise a lot
are healthy*/

How can I extract the date **28 September 2011** from the entire file or string, regardless of the month in the date, or whether it's capitalized?

Comment: Hi Shabbu. Please describe your problem a bit better. Are all strings like that you have to substring? Because if it is only for this sentence then the solution is easy and you should do a stringsplit.

Comment: Extract the substring i.e . only date "28 september 2011" from a multiline string or file

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(your_string, paste('(?i)\\d+',month.name,'\\d+',collapse='|'))`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract date from given string in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405615/extract-date-from-given-string-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have more than one date you want to extract here, and that you want the result to be date types (if not, just pass them to `format()` with the `strptime()` specification you want, e.g. `%e %B %Y` - but converting to date first will standardize them, because, for example, you have a lowercase month name here).

What I'm doing here is using R's built-in `month.name` vector of full month names, and making a single regex string out of it that will match any text with any month name surrounded by date and year numbers. We end up with a list of character vectors, one vector for each document string, with all the date strings extracted from them in order, and then I map `as_date()` to them with the appropriate parse pattern so that they're actually R dates now.

```r
  library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
  library(tidyverse)

  string <- 
    "Analysis made on 28 september 2011 people who exercise a lot are healthy
Another analysis on 6 May 1998 found otherwise"

  pattern <-  
    paste("[:digit:]{1,2}", month.name, "[:digit:]{4}", 
          collapse = "|") %>% 
    regex(ignore_case = TRUE)

  pattern
#> [1] "[:digit:]{1,2} January [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} February [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} March [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} April [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} May [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} June [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} July [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} August [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} September [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} October [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} November [:digit:]{4}|[:digit:]{1,2} December [:digit:]{4}"
#> attr(,"options")
#> attr(,"options")$case_insensitive
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> attr(,"options")$comments
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> attr(,"options")$dotall
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> attr(,"options")$multiline
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "regex"     "pattern"   "character"

  str_extract_all(string, pattern) %>% 
    map(as_date, tz = "", format = "%e %B %Y")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2011-09-28" "1998-05-06"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>